# Phonegap 2.2 audio error when using absolute device URI

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, uri

I have an app that downloads a m4a file from a remote server and stores it locally on the IOS device using File API's in Phonegap 2.2.

I then go to play said file using the media API's but it gives me the following error

```
Unknown resource 'file://localhost/Users/warea/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/3F588513-B560-4A62-8D82-33FA03809295/Documents/fan.m4a'
2013-04-07 13:41:46.622 Infinite Storm[10017:c07] [LOG] playAudio():Audio Error: [object Object]
```

Although I the download is successful and I can link directly to the file (and play it).
Are there known issues with a absolute URI and the Media framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite an answer but a solution after looking though CDVSound.m I realised I could just ask for the file path

```
documents://soundname.m4a
```

and it would automatically map to the correct location.